# How to find the equivalent pixel format in skiasharp?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, skia, skiasharp

In system.drawing there is a pixelformat in which we have added the pixel format while creating the BITMAP.Kindly refer the below code.

```
   Bitmap image = new Bitmap((int)width, (int)height, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);
```

Since the system.Drawing is not supported in ASP.NET core we have used skiasharp.In which we cant find the pixel format for the bitmap.Kindly provide the equivalent pixelformat in skiasharp for below pixels.

```
PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed   
PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb    
PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed  
PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb 
PixelFormat.Format4bppIndexed
```

Can anyone please provide the suggestion for finding the equivalent pixel format type in skiasharp.

Thanks, 
Mohan S